# Me keyword not able to execute subroutine in derived class due to Shadows

Tags: vb.net

I am having some difficulty understanding how `Shadows` works when used with `Me`. The following is the code I wrote:

```
Module Module1
    Sub main()
        Dim c As New Customer()
        c.UseMe() 'See item 1 
        Console.WriteLine("----")
        c.DoSomething()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Person
    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Console.WriteLine("Person")
    End Sub

    Public Sub UseMe()
        Me.DoSomething() 'See item 2
        'See item 3
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Inherits Person

    Public Shadows Sub DoSomething()
        'See item 4
        Console.WriteLine("Customer")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The following is how I expect it to work (but it doesn't):

1. `c` is the object of the derived class but calls the `UseMe` method in class `Person`
2. The `Me` keyword behaves like an object referring to a current instance (which in this case is `c`)
3. Hence `Me.DoSomething = c.DoSomething` and hence control should move to the derived class
4. Once the control moves to the derived class, the compiler should execute the `DoSomething` in the derived class as it has shadowed the `DoSomething` in the base class. Hence the output should be *"Customer"*. But the output is *"Person"*

Can you please explain where my understanding is going wrong? I am wondering why `Shadows` is preventing  `Me.DoSomething()` from executing the `DoSomething` method in the derived class and instead is executing the one in the base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Shadows` is similar to `Overrides` except that the former always works on the type of the reference while the latter always works on the type of the object.  Consider the following code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim b1 As New Base
        Dim d As New Derived
        Dim b2 As Base = DirectCast(d, Base)

        b1.OverrideTest()
        b1.ShadowTest()
        d.OverrideTest()
        d.ShadowTest()
        b2.OverrideTest()
        b2.ShadowTest()

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module


Public Class Base

    Public Overridable Sub OverrideTest()
        Console.WriteLine("Base.OverrideTest")
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShadowTest()
        Console.WriteLine("Base.ShadowTest")
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class Derived
    Inherits Base

    Public Overrides Sub OverrideTest()
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.OverrideTest")
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub ShadowTest()
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.ShadowTest")
    End Sub

End Class
```

The output from this code is as follows:

```
Base.OverrideTest
Base.ShadowTest
Derived.OverrideTest
Derived.ShadowTest
Derived.OverrideTest
Base.ShadowTest
```

So, when using a `Base` reference to a `Base` object, both methods invoke the base implementation. No surprise there. When using a `Derived` reference to a `Derived` object, both methods invoke the derived implementation. No surprise there either. On the other hand, when using a `Base` reference to a `Derived` object, the overridden method invokes the derived implementation, i.e. works on the type of the object, while the shadowed method invokes the base implementation, i.e. works on the type of the reference.

In your code, you are using `Me` in the `Person` class. `Me` is obviously a reference to the current object but it can only be a reference of the current type, i.e. the type the code is actually in.  Your code using `Me` is in the base type so it will always invoke base implementations of shadowed members.

Answer (score 0):

False assertions:

*"Hence `Me.DoSomething = c.DoSomething` and hence control should move to derived class"*

and

*"Hence the Output should be "Customer". But the output is "Person""*

**Explanation**

`Shadows` only mean that when you do `myClass.Method`, the method in derived class will be called. But if you call a method defined in base class and it calls another method defined in it, it will call that method. Unless, this is `overridable` and your derived class overrides it, then the behaviour would be more like you're expecting

```
Public Class Person
    Public Overridable Sub DoSomething()
        Console.WriteLine("Person")
    End Sub

    Public Sub UseMe()
        Me.DoSomething() 'STEP 2
        'STEP 3
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Inherits Person
    Public Overrides Sub DoSomething()
        'STEP 4
        Console.WriteLine("Customer")
    End Sub  
End Class
```